# How to assign default action to right click?

Tags: javascript

Don't know how to make it work, but I guess it's part of the learning process... Bellow is the code with two links, on that needs to be redirected, second one, regular... I want to make it that mouse actions on both links are identical (open on left click, open in new tab with middle click, properties on right click). Thank you all for your input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<a id="googlelink" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<hr>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<hr>

<script>

document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("click", redirectToYahoo);
document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("auxclick", redirectToYahooNewTab);
document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("contextmenu", rightClick);


function redirectToYahoo() { // LEFT MOUSE CLICK
    window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com";
}

function redirectToYahooNewTab() { // MIDDLE MOUSE CLICK
    window.open('https://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');
}

function rightClick() { // RIGHT MOUSE CLICK
    event.preventDefault();
};

</script>
</body>
```

Here is the snippet from @charlietfl that did the job.

```
var link = document.getElementById('googlelink');

link.addEventListener("auxclick",function(e){
   if(e.button !==2){
      window.open('https://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');
   }else{
     e.preventDefault()
   } 
});

link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com";
});

link.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
});
```

Comment: You mean in right click prevent from triggering `rightClick()`? Use `target.removeEventListener();`

Comment: Doesn't work, right click on link still acts like a click.

Comment: @DraganTomovski You used like this `document.getElementById("googlelink").removeEventListener("oncontextmenu", rightClick);` ? At the last line?

Comment: Did that too... 

Here is the html snipet:
<a id="googlelink" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>

So, this js should redirect link, but i want to keep default mouse click. As it is now, right click on link opens it in new focused tab, instead of properties or inspect of link...

Comment: @Colin Cline Yes, I just rechecked just now, doesn't work.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `auxclick`. Need to check which mouse button was used.

Not sure why you are using `auxclick` ... it has limited browser support.

A normal click listener won't trigger for right click. Also event name is `contextmenu` not `oncontextmenu`

```js
var link = document.getElementById('test');

link.addEventListener("auxclick",function(e){
   if(e.button !==2){
      console.log('Aux normal');
       e.preventDefault();
   }else{
      console.log('Aux right click')
   } 
});

link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('Normal click')// no log when right click
  e.preventDefault() // just for demo

})

link.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
  console.log('Context menu')
  e.preventDefault() 

})
```

```html
<a id="test" href="/questions">Stackoverflow Questions</a>
```

Comment: Whooooah! update the question with clarifications and additional code. dropping code into comments is very very hard to read

Comment: Really not clear at all what you are attempting to accomplish either. Put more attention on explanation also

Comment: I made a bloody mess, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your auxclick issue, but it answers how to do the rightclick as per the title:

Change `oncontextmenu` to `contextmenu`. Then prevent the default event:

```js
document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("contextmenu", rightClick);
    
function rightClick() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Right click disabled");
    // do your stuff here
};
```

```html
<button id="googlelink">googlelink</button>
```

Comment: I don't want to hide it, i want to make it to act like a regular right click on link  that pop up properties on link.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be helpful:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("googlelink");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  replace();
});

function replace() {
  link.href = "https://www.yahoo.com";
}
```

```html
<a id="googlelink" href="www.google.com"> GOOGLE LINK </a>
```

Comment: Did you wish to accomplish something like that ?

Comment: I updated the original question with the code in question, I hope it is more understandable now.